# Token Method in ASP.NET, Accepting every HTTP method in curl

Tags: c#, .net, windows, curl, asp.net-web-api

I am trying curl, These requests are storming my brain. The environment, I am using is OS - **Windows**, Command line interface - **Powershell**.

```
curl.exe -X GET -v local.qaapi.com/Token -d "username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX&clientid=XXXXX&grant_type=XXXXXX"

curl.exe -X POST -v local.qaapi.com/Token -d "username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX&clientid=XXXXX&grant_type=XXXXXX"
```

Both of them are giving the same output, But in case of **POST-MAN**(UI interface for requesting API-call's) Only **POST** call is working and **GET** call is blocked.I tried to **GET-METHOD** though knowing that it is not correct syntax, expected a fail-case but it has succeeded. CorsMiddleware Class, I had used for enable configuration setup for my API's.

Comment: You're doing legal HTTP requests with these curl commands, but we can't tell if they're done in the way you'd like them...

Comment: @DanielStenberg is my sentence looks like a blaming, if so sorry. But both of you are comments are a little bit confusing because in the first comment you said unusual and second one legal requests. But I am able to differentiate with POSTMAN, is there any additional settings do I need to enable in my code?

Comment: You're not clearly articulating how you want the requests to look like over the wire. For example: do you want the GET request to send a request-body or pass the data in the query part of the URL?

Comment: Basically, I am developing this API for creating a token which is like accessing token for users, whoever uses my API call in C#. I had enabled it for only POST method in my backend code. But when I was trying with CURL, it was working for both methods. But In case of the postman(UI interface of API request call), It is not working for GET  method. From that moment, it was storming my brain. And also I am a beginner in CURL and C# developing. If possible can you share your knowledge on curl and it backend architecture of curl? :)

Comment: You probably want something else different in the requests than just the method.

Comment: I am using "CorsMiddleware Class" for enabling configuration setup for my API'S. Do you have any idea about corsMiddleware Class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158039/discussion-between-kvk30-and-daniel-stenberg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions is asp.net identity core class. which you can find under this namespace `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth`.

There is a method in this library, `request.method`. It will show the API method name.