# ASP.NET Identity Token Methods accepts all HTTP methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I created pone webapi and implemented authentication. I have the token method to get the user token. All working fine.

**Scenario:**
I tested the token method with the postman. Here I noted that I can use any type of HTTP method to request for the token. I think /token method should support POST method only. But when I use DELETE method also I got token. Same as, I can also use PUT, PATH etc.

Is this expected? I assume that it should return Method Not Supported other than POST requests.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue, but it was in curl. can you please check that method in curl and tell me the output? Please check the link,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049550/same-output-for-different-request-method-types-in-curl

Comment: You can write your custom OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.Provider. And use the context to accept Http Post request only.

Comment: @kvk30, As you specified, i also tried in curl and got the same issue

Comment: @Saadi can you please tell the library names for enabling those option?

Comment: OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions is asp.net identity core class. which you can find under this namespace `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth`

Comment: @Saadi, in my case it was not allowing GET method through postman but in case of curl, it is allowing. For enabling those settings I am using coresmiddlecore class. above mention Owin.security.Oauth is an additional setting?

Comment: @Saadi, It has worked for me. I had define my own(Oauth) methods, where I restricted method from the command line. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Would you like, that I can post answer so that other users can see it?

Comment: @saadi you can post the answer to my question too, it would be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your custom OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.Provider. And use the context to accept Http Post request only

OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions is asp.net identity core class. which you can find under this namespace Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.

Sample Code:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
    }

    public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            if (context.Request.Method != "POST")
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_request", "Invalid request");
                return;
            }

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please write that method name too(`request.method()`), so that it gives more clarity.

Comment: `You can write your custom OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.Provider` How?

Comment: If it worked for you, can you please make this answer as useful (by click on up arrow)?
It'll be very helpful for other people and as well as me.